# How to remove orphaned tasks in Apache Mesos?

Tags: mesos, marathon

The problem maybe caused by Mesos and Marathon [out of sync](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/616), but the solution mentioned on GitHub doesn't work for me.

When I found the orphaned tasks:

[image]

What I do is:

1. restart Marathon
2. Marathon does not sync orphaned tasks, but start new tasks.
3. Orphaned tasks **still took the resources**, so I have to delete them.
4. I find all orphaned tasks under framework `ef169d8a-24fc-41d1-8b0d-c67718937a48-0000`,

   ```
   curl -XGET `http://c196:5050/master/frameworks
   ```

   shows that framework is `unregistered_frameworks`:

   ```
   {
       "frameworks": [
           .....
       ],
       "completed_frameworks": [ ],
       "unregistered_frameworks": [
           "ef169d8a-24fc-41d1-8b0d-c67718937a48-0000",
           "ef169d8a-24fc-41d1-8b0d-c67718937a48-0000",
           "ef169d8a-24fc-41d1-8b0d-c67718937a48-0000"
       ]
   }
   ```
5. Try to delete framework by framework ID (so that the tasks under framework would be delete too)

   ```
   curl -XPOST http://c196:5050/master/teardown -d 'frameworkId=ef169d8a-24fc-41d1-8b0d-c67718937a48-0000'
   ```

   but get `No framework found with specified ID`

So, how to delete orphaned tasks?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options

1. Register framework with same framework id. Do reconciliation and kill all tasks you receive. For example you can do it in following manner

   - Download the code `git clone https://github.com/janisz/mesos-cookbook.git`
   - Change dir `cd mesos-cookbook/4_understanding_frameworks`
   - In `scheduler.go` change master for your URL
   - If you want to mimic some other framework create `/tmp/framework.json` and fill it with [`FrameworkInfo`](https://github.com/janisz/mesos-cookbook/blob/master/4_understanding_frameworks/mesos.proto#L208) data:

     ```
     {
       "id": "<mesos-framewokr-id>",
       "user": "<framework-user>",
       "name": "<framework-name>",
       "failover_timeout": 3600,
       "checkpoint": true,
       "hostname": "<hostname>",
       "webui_url": "<framework-web-ui>"
     }
     ```
   - Run it `go run scheduler.go scheduler.pb.go mesos.pb.go`
   - Get list of all tasks `curl localhost:9090`
   - Delete task with  curl -X DELETE "http://10.10.10.10:9090/?id=task_id"
2. Wait until `failover_timeout` so Mesos will delete this tasks for you.