# Docker Containers on Marathon disappeared

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon

I have had been having great success so far using Mesos, Marathon, and Docker to manage a fleet of servers, and the containers I'm placing on them.

However, due to some problems I had to destroy my MesosMaster machine and now when I started the machine again and connected it with zookeeper cluster, I dont see anymore docker containers on marathon.

Those docker containers are running since they run on MesosSlaves and I can see them running when I ssh into those slave servers. But they no longer appear on Marathon GUI.

Now I can go back and start all the containers again on marathon GUI manually(takes alot of time) but I think that there has to be another smarter way to it.

Can somebody help me out here because my understanding of the logic of mesos, zookeeper tells me that my above actions should not have implications and mesos cluster should be smart enough to see the docker containers.

Comment: Can you see this containers in Mesos Master UI or in [/state](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/slave/state/). Probably the fastest way will be recover ZK state from snapshot/backup.

Comment: So you had only one master? If so, that's generally a very bad idea...

Comment: @tobi Yeah in hindsight, I regret just having 1 master. 
janisz I can see it as a orphan task in mesos gui but not as an active task.

Comment: I suspect your marathon get new framework id but recover it's state from ZK so Mesos didn't inform it about orphaned tasks during reconciliation because framework id didn't match. If you change Marathon framework id now you will end up in the same situation. I think you should kill those tasks [see how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40161740/1387612)

Comment: @janisz  I already started new containers on marathon since I could not wait (company pressure). But thanks. Maybe I will come back and test your suggestion 1 day.